# Prompt SPEAK dialog in Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor

Is it possible to use Sitecore specific prompt dialog in Experience Editor, like this below?
[image]
If so, can somebody provide an example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.prompt usually used for this, here an example below for Experience Editor ribbon button:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
    Sitecore.Commands.MyCommand =
    {
        canExecute: function(context) {
            return true;
        },
        execute: function (context) {
            ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.prompt("Enter a value:", "Default value", function (newValue) {
                ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.alert(newValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this blog before to create a custom dialog when publishing an item through the experience editor: https://blog.istern.dk/2015/03/02/running-sitecore-field-editor-from-a-speak-command-in-sitecore-experience-editor/